# Remove SID with ICACLS

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, access-control-list

I am trying to remove an obsolete SID (the account was apparently deleted).

I've tried to run the following on the server (win2003) and a client (win7):

```
icacls c:\path /remove *S-1-5-21-1883347182-1220252494-433279356-1095 /T
```

But I always get the output

```
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

without it doing anything. How can I get it to work?

Update:

I've used [AccessEnum](https://serverfault.com/questions/165261/acl-monitoring-reporting) to get the SID because icacls only says "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done." but doesn't show the sid.

The output from AccessEnum is:

```
"Path"  "Read"  "Write" "Deny"  
"c:\path"   "Administrators, S-1-5-21-1883347182-1220252494-433279356-1095, ..."    "Administrators, S-1-5-21-1883347182-1220252494-433279356-1095, ..."    ""
```

Comment: Could you post a relevant snip of the output of icacls "C:\path"? Are you positive that SID is correct?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK the SID is correct - see my update.

Comment: Does this SID have an entry in the ACL of the parent folder, C:\ in your question?  If not, you may be able to use the `/reset` switch of `icalcs` -- *e.g.* `icacls C:\path /reset /T`

Comment: I also have this problem, and I see exactly the same behaviour from `icacls`... still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion to another [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/198163/how-to-clean-up-orphaned-sids-in-aces-in-ad/221730#221730)

"perhaps you're looking for SUBINACL. Download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en)

**subinacl.exe /help /cleandeletedsidsfrom** provides the following:

/cleandeletedsidsfrom=domain[=dacl|sacl|owner|primarygroup|all]

delete all ACEs containing deleted (no valid) Sids from DomainName
You can specify which part of the security descriptor will be scanned
(default=all)
If the owner is deleted, new owner will be the Administrators group.
If the primary group is deleted, new primary group will be the Users group.
Appears you can use this with */file* or */share* or */subdirectories* as needed

Answer (score 2):

I have found the most portable and actually easiest way to be using the `/save` and `/restore` functions of `icacls`:

```
icacls C:\ /save D:\creds.txt /T
```

And then I would use Vim, or some other `gred/sed/awk` equivalent to manipulate the file. That allows me to remove SID, replace SID, etc. After I'm finished with the file I do

```
icacls C:\ /restore D:\creds.new.txt /T
```

That it. No need to download other programs. No need to learn yet another non standard command line syntax. I just create a dummy file and use the GUI or whatever to make the ACL exactly the way I want it, use `/save` to see how the resultant ACE string looks like, then just copy and paste that ACE string into `creds.new.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com):

```
SetACL -on C:\Path -ot file -actn trustee -trst 
       "n1:S-1-5-21-1883347182-1220252494-433279356-1095;s1:y;ta:remtrst;w:dacl"
```

Comment: With the current SetACL 3.0.6 version this goes like this: `SetACL -on C:\path -ot file -actn delorphanedsids -rec cont_obj`

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the GUI? Bring up the folder properties and remove the unwanted SID from the security settings. That's always worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but we have thousands of folders! I would prefer to use the AccessEnum output in a script :)

Comment: You cannot do that for NULL SIDS